# ASP .NET WebService sending array to the Ajax

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, web-services

Hi I'm trying to return string to my textboxes by click on a repeater row item 
here the web method;

```
   [WebMethod]
    public string  OrderGet(int User)
    {
        using (Models.DermabonEntities db = new Models.DermabonEntities())
        {



            var get = (from i in db.OrderAddress
                       where i.Id == User
                       select i.UserId).ToList();

            var a = get.FirstOrDefault().ToString();

            var res = (from i in db.OrderAddress
                       where i.UserId == a
                       select i.FirstName).FirstOrDefault();

            var res1 = (from i in db.OrderAddress
                        where i.UserId == a
                        select i.LastName).FirstOrDefault();

            object[] array1 = new object[2];

            array1[0] = res;
            array1[1] = res1;

            return array1.ToString();

        }
    }
```

As you see I return array1 
here the ajax code;

```
function siparisAl(id) {

      var User = id;



      $.ajax({
          dataType: "json",
          type: "POST",
          contentType: "application/json",
          url: "/Admin/WebService/Control.asmx/OrderGet",
          data: JSON.stringify({ 'User': User }),
          success: function (data) {

              $("#ContentPlaceHolder1_Name").val(data.d[0]);

                },
          error: function () {

          }
      });
      return false;
  }
```

the problem is when I run it writes S to the Name textbox why it could be ? And How can I fix it I have several names in my database instead of 'S' please help

and I've tried console.log(data.d) = it says System.Object[]

Comment: Can you clarify what your problem is (I'm having a little bit of trouble understanding what you're saying is happening)?

Comment: let me explain I have a repeater of ordered products I list them with repeater and in the repeater I have little descriptions like name surname and I have a ımage button for per row when you click it send order Id to the ajax then webservice. So I control the Id and then I return full description to the dialog box. which is name surname address etc but the problem is when I return array it doesnt give the name and surname it gives 'S'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to return a string, change the code from:

```
return array1.ToString();
```

To:

```
return res + res1;
```

In the first snippet your are not returning the concatenated string, but calling the ToString method of the object array. Which is `System.Object[]`.

**Edit:**

To access `res` and `res1` separately, you could return:

```
return new { First = res, Second = res1};
```

And in the success callback of your ajax call:

```
data.First
data.Second
```

Use `console.log(data)` to check the response, you should be able to figure it out.

**Edit2:**

To return a list of string, change the web method signature to:

```
public List<string> OrderGet(int User)
```

And in the ajax call, the data object will be an array.

**Suggestion:**

Please, you should improve your code quality. Check the C# naming convention and best practices.

**Edit3:**

If you are using an anonymous object, like in the first edit, you need to return an anonymous object from your web service, so change the signature to:

```
public dynamic OrderGet(int User)
```